# Android, Handler is running in main thread or other thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have following code.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    private int _splashTime = 5000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread(){
           @Override
           public void run(){
             Intent mainMenu = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
             SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
             SplashScreen.this.finish();
             overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.fadein, R.drawable.fadeout);
           }
        }, _splashTime);
    }
}
```

I have problem in analyze of this code. As far as know handler is running in main thread. but it has thread which is running in other thread.

**MainMenu.class** will be run in main thread or second thread?
if main **thread** is stopped for 5 seconds ANR will be raise. Why when I am stopping it with delay `(_splashTime)` ANR doesn't display (even if i increase it to more than 5 seconds)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As far as know handler is running in main thread.

Objects do not run on threads, because objects do not run. Methods run.

> but it has thread which is running in other thread.

You have not posted any code which involves any "other thread". Everything in the code listing above is tied to the main application thread of your process.

> MainMenu.class will be run in main thread or second thread?

Objects do not run on threads, because objects do not run. Methods run. `MainMenu` appears to be an `Activity`. The activity lifecycle methods (e.g., `onCreate()`) are called on the main application thread.

> Why when I am stopping it with delay (_splashTime) ANR doesn't display (even if i increase it to more than 5 seconds)

You are not "stopping [the main application thread] with delay". You have scheduled a `Runnable` to be run on the main application thread after a delay `_splashTime` milliseconds. However, `postDelayed()` is not a blocking call. It simply puts an event on the event queue that will not be executed for `_splashTime` milliseconds.

Also, please replace `Thread` with `Runnable`, since `postDelayed()` does not use `Thread`. Your code compiles and runs, because `Thread` implements `Runnable`, but you will confuse yourself by thinking that using `Thread` instead of `Runnable` means that your code will run on a background thread, and it will not.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Murphy. It shows in what extent I didn't get concepts of Java and Android :) I thought that when we have "new Thread()" in new Handler().postDelayed then new thread will be created.

Comment: @Hesam: Well, you are creating an instance of a `Thread` object. However, an actual OS *thread* is not created unless somebody calls `start()` on your `Thread` object. Since `postDelayed()` is just thinking of the object as a `Runnable`, `postDelayed()` will not call `start()`, just `run()`. Hence, your `run()` code will be executed on the main application thread, not a background thread.

Comment: so much useful info in a single answer.

Comment: Is method `run()`, on being started running on a different thread due to `new Thread() { }` or on main application thread?

Comment: @M.S.: If you are referring to `run()` on the `Runnable` passed to `postDelayed()`, it will be run on the main application thread.